# Spring boot @Scheduled(cron) for every 2 hour

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to trigger my function every 2 hours.

***Could you please provide `@Scheduled` expression for this case?***

Example:

> @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?", zone = "Asia/Calcutta")

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks     
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: 0 0 0/2 ? * * *

Comment: Is it possible to give the start time, after that It will trigger every 2 hour

Answer (score 12):

Please use pattern of cron

```
@Scheduled(cron = "[Seconds] [Minutes] [Hours] [Day of month] [Month] [Day of week] [Year]"
```

You need bellow pattern to run the task in every 2 hours

```
 0 0 */2 * * ?
```

(At second :00, at minute :00, every 2 hours starting at 00am, of every day)

You can test your cron pattern with [freeformatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)